# Relation between the unit sample sequence δ[n] and the unit step sequence u[n]

Tags: signal-processing

The discrete time unit step is given by $$ u[n] =
\begin{cases}
1, & n \geq 0, \\
0, & n < 0.
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$

Unit Sample sequence or Impulse sequence is defined as $$ δ[n] =
\begin{cases}
1, & n = 0, \\
0, & n ≠ 0.
\end{cases}
\tag{2}
$$

and they are related via the sum relation by $$ u[n] =
\sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty  \delta[k]. \tag{3}$$

The Question is : how to verify the relation between these ? $$ u[n] =
\sum_{m = 0}^\infty  \delta[n-m] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty  \delta(k),
$$
$$\delta[n]=u[n]-u[n-1].\tag{4}
$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please enter your mathematical expressions as text instead of linking to images. Use MathJax to format the expressions; you can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion

Comment: HINT: $u[n] = \sum_k \delta[k]$ represents integration. So, $u[n]$ should look like a step function. For other case, i.e., $\delta [n] = u[n] - u[n-1]$ represents derivative... just think about it...